# vim opening several recent files into tabs

Tags: vim

In Vim, I know I can do this to see a list of recently opened files and select one for editing:

```
:browse old
```

But is there a way to choose several at once in one go?  And bonus: can I open them into tabs instead of buffers?

I'd prefer a native (non-plugin) way if possible.

UPDATE: I finally settled for a plugin called MRU that's actually pretty good.  It lets me browse and open multiple recent files into tabs, which matches my workflow perfectly.

UPDATE #2: I just learned that vim lets you save your current work state, including all the opened tabs/buffers, into a "session" which you can then reload the next time you open vim (saves by default into Session.vim, you can optionally append a filename to change that).
To create/save your current workstate:

```
:mks
```

Then later to restore from your session:

```
vim -S
```

Note that vim creates the Session.vim file in the current dir, not ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are also stored as a List in the `v:oldfiles` variable. From there, you could loop over them and query for multiple files. That could be a custom mapping or command that you write.

Opening just the last N (here: `3`) in tabs can for example be achieved with

```
:for file in v:oldfiles[0:2] | execute 'tabedit' fnameescape(file) | endfor
```